# Custom UICollectionView Layout

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

The UICollectionView layout I need to implement contains three sections, one below the other vertically, and each section is scrollable horizontally.

SECTION 1: 1 2 3 4 5 ..............

SECTION 2: 1 2 3 4 5 ..............

SECTION 3: 1 2 3 4 5 ..............

Since the UICollectionView has only one scrollView, all the sections scroll at a time but not one at a time. So I feel custom Layout won't help in this situation. Please throw some light on other possible implementations of this.

Thank you.

Comment: If you only need the 3 rows, and that's all you'll ever need, then I would just use 3 collection views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a `UITableView` with three custom `UITableViewCell` each of them containing one `UICollectionView`?

Comment: My layout is kind of ARC shape looks like orbits, looking for much better solution. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Since I there is no autorotation in my app, using three collectionViews, with a subClass of FlowLayout and overriding the center for each layout attributes for each item relative to the x-distance of the item from the center of the collectionView did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

One `UITableView` with 3 rows. Each with a `UICollectionView`.

Comment: In that case I don't even need tableView, I can directly add three CollectionViews to superView, but in my layout each Section is an ARC shape kind of Orbits. I am looking for a much cleaner solution. Much appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: It's a clean solution if you know what you are doing.

Comment: @JackBoy I mean to say, I am looking for a much lighter(less number of views) solution, thanks for your help.

Comment: Less number of Views? Have fun handling the rotation of 3 `UICollectionViews` vs one `UITableView`.